# How to parse Text element in SVG swift?

Tags: swift, cashapelayer, svgkit, swiftsvg, pocketsvg

I am using **PocketSVG, SwiftSVG and SVGKit** libraries to parse SVG elements and convert into CALayer. But I don't know how to parse **Text** element and its *attributes* from SVG in swift.

I want to get **My Text** string from below SVG text element. How can I parse it?

```
<text x="20" y="35" class="small">My Text</text>
```

Comment: An SVG file is XML ... you can parse it just like any other XML file.

Comment: Currently `PocketSVG` library doesn't support `text` tag. Not sure about `SwiftSVG` and `SVGKit`